# Increment string if exists

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, linq, ienumerable

I need a piece of code that increments end of string in "[]" brackets, but I got headache with that.

Thing is, if name "test" exists in given collection, algorithm should return `test_[0]`, if both exists then "test_[1]" etc. That works so far. But when I tried to pass as currentName value "test_[something]" algorithm creates something like `test_[0]_[0]`, `test_[0]_[1]` instead of `test_[somenthing+someNumber]`. Does anyone know the way to change this behavior?

```
//                                           test                   test, test_[2], test_[3]
protected string GetDistinctName2(string currentName, IEnumerable<string> existingNames)
{
    int iteration = 0;
    if (existingNames.Any(n => n.Equals(currentName)))
    {
        do
        {
            if (!currentName.EndsWith($"({iteration})"))
            {
                currentName = $"{currentName}_[{++iteration}]";
            }
        }
        while (existingNames.Any(n => n.Equals(currentName)));
    }

    return currentName;
}
```

EDIT :
The best solution so far is that(I can bet that I've seen it here, but someone had to delete)

```
public static void Main()
{
        var currentOriginal = "test";
        var existingNamesOriginal = new[] { "test", "test_[2]", "test_[3]" };
        string outputOriginal = GetDistinctNameFromSO(currentOriginal, existingNamesOriginal);
        Console.WriteLine("original : " + outputOriginal);

        Console.ReadLine();
}

    protected static string GetDistinctNameFromSO(string currentName,
                                             IEnumerable<string> existingNames)
    {
        if (null == currentName)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(currentName));
        else if (null == existingNames)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(existingNames));

        string pattern = $@"^{Regex.Escape(currentName)}(?:_\[(?<Number>[0-9]+)\])?$";

        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);

        var next = existingNames
          .Select(item => regex.Match(item))
          .Where(match => match.Success)
          .Select(match => string.IsNullOrEmpty(match.Groups["Number"].Value)
             ? 1
             : int.Parse(match.Groups["Number"].Value))
          .DefaultIfEmpty()
          .Max() + 1;

        if (next == 1)
            return currentName; // No existingNames - return currentName
        else
            return $"{currentName}_[{next}]";
    }
```

For given "test" string it returns "test_[4]" which is excellent, but if given string is let's say "test_[2]" it should also return "test_[4]"(string with given pattern with first free number), but it returns "test_[2]_[2]" instead.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. Your question has a low quality. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve query, consider reading the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)*.

Comment: Please be more elaborate, OP

Comment: instead of passing `currentName = "test_[0]"` as parameter, pass `currentName = "test", iteration = 0`, so both parts (name and iteration) are variabilized in method signature

Comment: Iterative solutions based on formatting and comparing strings start to get into performance issues with a few thousand items, are you ok with that?

Comment: In your test with `EndsWith` you use round brackets "()", but the input contains square brackets "[]"

Comment: @GvS, good catch is that enought for beeing a typo?. The change is enought to make the function work https://dotnetfiddle.net/HMha1h for that test case.

Comment: If the test with `EndsWith` fails, the `iteration` variable does not increment, and you end up in a neverending loop.

Comment: You should definitely be using `_[]` in your `EndsWith`. Also, passing in `IEnumerable<string>` and then testing with `Any` multiple times is terribly inefficient. You should either pass in `HashSet<string>` or convert to it once at the top of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler rewrite:

```
protected string GetDistinctName2(string currentName, IEnumerable<string> existingNames)
{
    int iteration = 0;
    var name = currentName;

    while(existingNames.Contains(name))
    {   
        name = currentName + "_[" + (iteration++) + "]";
    }

    return name;
}
```

Tests:

```
GetDistinctName2("test", new List<string> {"test", "test_[0]", "test_[2]", "test_[3]"}).Dump();//Out: test_[1]
GetDistinctName2("test", new List<string> {"test", "test_[0]", "test_[1]", "test_[2]", "test_[3]"}).Dump();//Out: test_[4]
GetDistinctName2("test", new List<string> {}).Dump();//Out: test
```

Comment: I suggest copying `IEnumerable<string>` to a `HashSet<string>` is worthwhile assuming you may iterate a few times.

Answer (score 0):

I will try answer with minimal adjustments to your code:

1. Use square brackets to check if name exists
2. Use a local variable to prevent adding [0] over and over
3. increment `iteration` on every do/while loop
4. if the result, should never be "test", exclude it from the existing results

The result looks like (not tested, but this should get you on your way):

```
//                                           test                   test, test_[2], test_[3]
protected string GetDistinctName2(string currentName, IEnumerable<string> existingNames)
{
    int iteration = 0;

    // Use a different variable this will prevent you from adding [0] again and again
    var result = currentName;
    if (existingNames.Where(s => s != currentName).Any(n => n.Equals(result)))
    {
        do
        {

            // Use square brackets
            if (!result .EndsWith($"[{iteration}]"))
            {
                result = $"{currentName}_[{iteration}]";
            }
            iteration++; // Increment with every step
        }
        while (existingNames.Any(n => n.Equals(result)));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your description of your problem and your code and completely different. Here will increment a number inside the square brackets without appending additional text.

The change from the initial code addresses a problem mentioned in the question about including text inside the square brackets with a number. Below you can replace `something` with other text.

```
protected string GetDistinctName2(string currentName, IEnumerable<string> existingNames)
{
    int iteration = 0;
    string nextName = currentName;
    while (existingNames.Contains(nextName))
    {
        nextName = $"{currentName}_[something{iteration}]";
        iteration++;
    }

    return nextName;
}
```

C# interactive shell example:

```
> GetDistinctName2("test", new List<string>() { "test", "test_[something0]", "test_[something1]"})
"test_[something2]"
```

Comment: Can you please expand on how this addresses the OP issue and why the OP is causing issues?

Comment: *"I'm not seeing your iteration variable being incremented in your code."* there : `currentName = $"{currentName}_[{++iteration}]";` (note the `++iteration`)